# Qt Creator : generate UUID for c++ header

Tags: qt-creator

Is it possible to generate UUID inside Qt Creator editor for c++ header files. For example, I'd like to get something like

```
#ifndef _f6198c0e_13c3_4641_af52_140d11befb93_
#define _f6198c0e_13c3_4641_af52_140d11befb93_
#endif
```

where "_f6198c0e_13c3_4641_af52_140d11befb93_" is generaed by IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have for the moment is to develop a Qt Creator plugin. Here is my source code to get what I want :

```
  void MyPluginPlugin::triggerAction()
  {
     auto ret = QUuid::createUuid().toString();
     ret = ret.replace('{', '_');
     ret = ret.replace('}', '_');
     ret = ret.replace('-', '_');

     auto clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
     clipboard->setText( ret );

     QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_V, Qt::ControlModifier );
     QCoreApplication::postEvent( QApplication::focusWidget(), event);
  }
```